# Destination array is not long enough to copy all the items in the collection. Check array index and length

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, multithreading, dictionary

I have this code. It gives me an error :

> Destination array is not long enough to copy all the items in the
>   collection. Check array index and length.

I thought that it was because of using a dictionary, so I switched it to `ConcurrentDictionary`, but the error is still here.

```
private void SaverCallback()
{
    AddThread("Main Thread");
    const string path = "milestone";
    while (!stop)
    {
        ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> milestone = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, object>();
        milestone.TryAdd("Jobs", JobQueue.Queue.MainQueue);
        milestone.TryAdd("Locked Jobs", JobQueue.Queue.LockedQueue);

    again: try {
            using (FileStream writingStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {
                BinaryFormatter formater = new BinaryFormatter();
                formater.Serialize(writingStream, milestone);
                writingStream.Flush();
                Logger.Debug("Status saved");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Logger.Error($"Milestone exception: {e.Message}");
            goto again;
        }
        this.WaitTime(60000);
    }
    RemoveThread();
}
```

**UPD:**

> Destination array is not long enough to copy all the items in the
>   collection. Check array index and length. and    at
>   System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource) 
>   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.CopyTo(KeyValuePair`2[]
>   array, Int32 index)    at
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo
>   info, StreamingContext context)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize(Object
>   obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context,
>   SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter,
>   ObjectWriter objectWriter, SerializationBinder binder)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Write(WriteObjectInfo
>   objectInfo, NameInfo memberNameInfo, NameInfo typeNameInfo)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.WriteArrayMember(WriteObjectInfo
>   objectInfo, NameInfo arrayElemTypeNameInfo, Object data)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.WriteArray(WriteObjectInfo
>   objectInfo, NameInfo memberNameInfo, WriteObjectInfo memberObjectInfo)
>   at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Write(WriteObjectInfo
>   objectInfo, NameInfo memberNameInfo, NameInfo typeNameInfo)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize(Object
>   graph, Header[] inHeaders, __BinaryWriter serWriter, Boolean fCheck)
>   at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream
>   serializationStream, Object graph, Header[] headers, Boolean fCheck)
>   at AggregateRunner.Enteties.Saver.SaverCallback()

Comment: don't use `goto`. it indicates a major design issue. the only languages where jumps are allowed are IL and ASM

Comment: What is the type of `JobQueue.Queue.MainQueue` and `JobQueue.Queue.LockedQueue`?

Comment: @MatthewWatson some kind of thread pools

Comment: So can another thread be adding items to the job queue while it is being serialised as part of the serialisation of `milestone`? If so, perhaps something bad is happening during that process.

Comment: @MatthewWatson but in my case I use ConcurrentDictionary, so this should not be a problem, yes?

Comment: so, if there is an exeption, log it and retry, using a goto, ad infinitum. Doesn't it sound bad?

Comment: It's probably not the ConcurrentDictionary that's causing problems, but the JobQueue that's stored in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid this error I use lock before a try to serialize a file.
Now it works correctly.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can see, you're taking a snapshot for your queues once an hour, but the main problem with your code is that you're trying to serialize your queue (which is a `ConcurrentQueue<T>`, I guess) itself without any cloning or synchronization logic. Another problem with your code is a `goto` usage, which is not necessary at all here.

The exception you're facing is a `ArgumentException` and is a [third possible exception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287188.aspx#Exceptions) of `CopyTo` method of the `ConcurrentQueue<T>`. It's happening during the serialization because of some thread added some messages to queue and now it doesn't fit in array serializer decided to use.

So, what you can do in such situation is either introduce some locking during access to the original queues (which you're decided to do), or create a clone for your queues and serialize that in a safe manner without blocking other threads.

You can do this with [`CopyTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287188.aspx) method of `ConcurrentQueue<T>` by yourself, with creating array with length more than number of messages in queue, but the locking in general is more convenient way to clone the data. So your code should be like this:

```
private void SaverCallback()
{
    AddThread("Main Thread");
    const string path = "milestone";
    while (!stop)
    {
        try
        {
            lock (JobQueue.Queue.MainQueue)
            lock (JobQueue.Queue.LockedQueue)
            {
                using (var writingStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
                {
                    var milestone = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, object>();
                    milestone.TryAdd("Jobs", JobQueue.Queue.MainQueue);
                    milestone.TryAdd("Locked Jobs", JobQueue.Queue.LockedQueue);

                    var formater = new BinaryFormatter();
                    formater.Serialize(writingStream, milestone);
                    writingStream.Flush();
                    Logger.Debug("Status saved");
                }
            }
            // this line cloud be in finally case too,
            // if you don't need to save a queue in case of some errors
            this.WaitTime(60000);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            // note that logger accepts whole exception information
            // instead of only it's message
            Logger.Error($"Milestone exception: {e}");
            continue;
        }
    }
    RemoveThread();
}
```